# How to obtain all the characters from a time stamp in a string

Tags: c++

I am finishing a game with a certain time limit on the pc. In order to 
get a new highscore you need to have a lower time than the current highscore.
This time gets written to a .txt file and is being retrieved when the game is restarted. With this being said the retrieved highscore from the .txt file is a string. In order to make a less or bigger than comparison, the Gametime should be converted to a string.

I am able to make the comparison and convert the the actual gametime to a string, however the conversion is incomplete. If the actual gametime is 02:30 the time in the conversion than is 30. It cuts the first part of.

First i put the actual gametime in a double:
nGameTimer is a counter.
    double GameTime = (nGameTimer / 60 , nGameTimer % 60);
     nGameTimer / 60  are the minutes 
     nGameTimer % 60  are the seconds

In order to convert it to a string i used this conversion which i found during my research.

```
std::ostringstream sstream;
sstream << GameTime;
std::string varAsString = sstream.str();
```

I have a suspicion that my assignment to the double gametime is where it first goes wrong!

How am I able to obtain the full timestamp of the actual gametime when I convert it to a string?

Comment: What do you expect `(nGameTimer / 60 , nGameTimer % 60)` to do?

Comment: "First i put the actual gametime in a double" No, you don't. Your code with comma operator is equivalent to `double GameTime = nGameTimer % 60;`.

Comment: You are correct, your assignment of `double GameTime` is incorrect. If you cast `nGameTimer` to a double, and then divide by 60, you should get what you want

Comment: Lookup `std::fioxed`, `std::setw` and `std::precision` IO manipulators.

Comment: @SteveLorimer I don't think casting to `double` is needed.

Comment: to summarize the comments: You are Wong on so many Levels... (plus you should have also show how the `nGameTimer` is declared.) BTW, what will happen when somebody will finish in just 59s? Or in 9s? Or will finish in 1h:00m:00s? ... you should sanitize the time to be compared/stored by some strict validation rules.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

And final note... if `nGameTimer` is total amount of seconds, just store that. And read it back as `unsigned` number (will work for games under 60 years duration correctly on 32b platform). Then compare the numbers, the lower one is better time.

Keep the time everywhere as the number, only when you are displaying it to user, create a utility helper function `std::string formatGameDuration(const unsigned gameDuration)`, and use that to convert the number into human formatted string.

While developing the formatter, use unit testing to verify it does produce correct string for many possible inputs (0s, 9s, 60s, 599s, 3600s, and other interesting durations (expecting probably "00:00", "00:09", "01:00", "09:59", "1h+").

Remember this pattern for future, especially if you will ever store date+time of some event. Always store UTC time in files/databases, and do the formatting only before displaying it to human (by formatting in this case is meant also adjusting the time by desired time zone for the output). Never store local times/dates, it causes lot of headaches later, in case that project gets larger than expected.

Comment: This is really a specific case of a more general rule of thumb: Store data in a lossless way, and if you drop information (e.g. for display), do it is late as possible. Don't use lossy data for code logic.

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
double GameTime = (nGameTimer / 60 , nGameTimer % 60);
```

uses a comma operator and is equivalent to

```
double GameTime = nGameTimer % 60;
```

You won't need such a thing and can do the conversion directly. Try this:

```
std::ostringstream sstream;
sstream << (nGameTimer / 60) << ':' << (nGameTimer % 60);
std::string varAsString = sstream.str();
```

Comment: Do you think it would be more beneficial to just use `to_string` and `+` to build the string?

Comment: While this code at least makes sense, the result will be not comparable in lexicographic way with other result. For example `true == "23:45" < "1:23"`.

Comment: *"is equivalent to"* - Not really. It produces the same result, sure. But since we don't know what type *nGameTimer* is, or whether there is an `operator/()` defined, that has side effects, there's no way to claim equivalence. Now that's not entirely likely, but still, this is C++, and things are subtle at times.

Comment: the above conversion works. the only thing now is , instead of only getting the seconds i only get the the last three digits. example , time = 01:23 i get  1:23. i need the format in 4 digits in order to do the comparison. is there a way to add the missing zero? i once saw a function to add the missing leading zero's.

Comment: i think something with setw() and setfill, but how do you use it with the output operator <<    in order to get the 4 digit format of time 00:00?

Comment: i think i got it.....  ostringstream sstream;
 sstream << setw(2) << setfill('0') << (nGameTimer / 60) << ':' << (nGameTimer % 60);
 string varAsString = sstream.str();

Comment: @D-Antonio: Time over 1h will still break it, unless you treat it specifically, like `if (60*60 <= nGameTimer) { sstream << "over 1h"; } else { ... }`, and 'o' is later in ASCII than any digit character, so this text will be always worse, than any proper time under 1h.